# I need help to upgrade my code to react-router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm making a course of react, and currently i'm learning react-router, but in the course the teacher uses the react-router v4, so i am constantly updating the code to the newest v6 version, but this time my code isn't returning my menu element, and i dont know what to do.

my code from main component:

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES,
    };
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
          <Route end path='/menu' element={() => <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />} />
          <Route path='/' element={<Navigate replace to='/home' />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

my code from menu component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardTitle } from 'reactstrap';

    function RenderMenuItem ({dish, onClick}) {
        return (
            <Card onClick={() => onClick(dish.id)}>
                <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                <CardImgOverlay>
                    <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                </CardImgOverlay>
            </Card>
        );
    }

    const Menu = (props) => {

        const menu = props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1"  key={dish.id}>
                    <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} />
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    {menu}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

export default Menu;
```

ps: the dishes is a json file that contain all the data to build the menu

## What i am trying to understand

I'm trying to render my menu, but isn't working, and i'm brazillian so sorry for any pronounce errors, i dont write in english constantly, so, if someone help me i'm gonna be so much grateful, im learning all this stuff and always have to update the code to the newest, if I didn't explain it so well in the post, please, if you have availability, send me a message on discord: vito#7104, or reply here, but anyways, thanks for any help given :).

Comment: Not related to your question, but you probably want to use some of the newer tutorial out there, and there're plentyful.

Comment: The `Menu` component doesn't render because you are passing a function to the `element` prop of the `Route` component instead of a `ReactNode`. Your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75260764/how-to-upgrade-my-code-to-react-router-v6) was closed as a duplicate. Please don't delete it and repost it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `element` property of the  component of react-router does not support a function but only a React component (see [Route type declaration](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#type-declaration): element?: React.ReactNode | null;).

Simply write: `<Route path='/menu' element={<Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />} />`

Comment: thank you so much :), sorry for bother with these type of question